# How to use javascript libraries imported from NPM

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, bundle

### Context

For a long time I was using Bootstrap and other libraries by sources. I mean I was including it as below:

```
- static
   - vendor
       - jquery
       - popper
       - bootstrap
       - ...
```

But nowadays, I need to *improve myself in managing* my web dependencies. For some reasons :

- Less sources in repositories and a more efficient team project
- Greater support to choose version or test migrations
- Saving time for later projects with same dependencies
- I need to include a library which is only provided through NPM which is [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html)

So I am currently trying to manage dependencies via NPM, in a **django project**. But I'm stuck at a very basic step *I guess*. I don't know **where to continue** after `npm install --save jquery popper.js bootstrap`. I'm disturbed by all examples which are for node.js application...

### Where I'm stuck

I have an `index.js` at the same level of my main `package.json`. I thought I had to import my scripts in this file, then include this script in my page. So I tried require Jquery then bootstrap, but I get errors on bootstrap required because `jquery` is undefined.
I don't have much code to show, the more I need is to understand how it works step by step rather than having it done to me.

---

### Questions

My primary goal is to manage my main javascripts, I mean scripts that must appear through the whole site. Wrap them into one script, then include this script in my `base.html` assuming I'm in a django project.

1. I know that bootstrap < v5 **depends on** Jquery and popper.js, but it comes with its own package.json, isn't that enough ? Do we have to `npm install jquery popper.js` them anyway, as some people suggest in some SO thread or else ? Even after running `npm install` inside the `node_module/bootstrap` ? Additionally, the `bootstrap.bundle.js` contains popper.js, and node_modules inside bootstrap contains jquery. **Why not use those ?** **See [Bootstrap import with webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/webpack/)** Otherwise why are they there ?
2. How to **bundle** my javascript dependencies ? Via **webpack** ? For example, Jquery from `bootstrap/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` with `bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js` ? Then I will have **same versions** used by bootstrap developers.
3. Then how to compile the wanted scripts into one script, and minify it for example ? Then I could get those scripts by `collectstatic` function into the folder where I group all my desired statics.

Perhaps I'm not clear, because all of this blurred my mind.

---

### Webography

[Use Sass/css within django, NPM way](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-use-scsssass-your-django-project-npm-way/)
[Add react in django project, via NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704733/adding-react-inside-a-django-project)
[Bootstrap package manager](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#package-managers)
[Bootstrap import with webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/webpack/)
[Npm install jquery, poper, bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470007/12668692)
[React with webpack](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/)

---

#### Editions with my progress

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "static_src",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Static files from NPM.",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx webpack -c webpack-conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "codemirror": "^5.58.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

### webpack-conf.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'dist/bootstrap-bundle.js' }
};
```

### index.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {} from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap'
```

### npm run build

```
> npx webpack -c webpack-conf.js

[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset dist/bootstrap-bundle.js 169 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
runtime modules 1.13 KiB 5 modules
cacheable modules 508 KiB
  ./index.js 71 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 281 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 140 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js 86.4 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.6.0 compiled successfully in 4541 ms
```

### Result

Well for now I manage to include this bundle into my site, but an error occured, and it seems not including Jquery : `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Notably it occurs on this snippet for example :

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a great solution !

### webpack-conf.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {path: __dirname, filename: 'dist/bootstrap-bundle.js'},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

### index.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
import {} from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap'
```

Then importing this script works well. Thanks to @Karanveer that unblurred my mind to put me on the right way. And this [thread about webpack issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4258)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Q1, assuming you have run `npm install bootstrap` and you can find 'popper' and 'jquery' in the node_modules folder:

- Add `import 'bootstrap';` in your index.js (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)

*NOTE:*

1. IF you cannot find 'popper' and 'jquery' in the node_modules folder, THEN It's worthwhile to install them via npm using `npm install @popperjs/core` & `npm install jquery`
2. IF you had to install popper and jQuery manually for some reason, THEN Add `import $ from 'jquery';` & `import {} from '@popperjs/core';` in your index.js

Comment: Do let me know if this helps you out!

Comment: (I think you made an error `import $ from 'bootstrap';` should be `from 'jquery'` right ? I did try `import 'bootstrap`, as i saw it in the bootstrap doc (see the webography). However, then I tried to run this script via `node index.js` and lead me to an error. But correct me if I am wrong, it's where I should [configuring my webpack](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/#Configuring_webpack) instead of trying to run the script ?

Comment: Let’s look at this again, 
1. You’re right, it should be `import $ from ‘jquery’`,  I’ve made the edit for the typo :)
2. You’d still need to import the ‘script’ in your app.js instead of your webpack.conf.js

A good reference is how we import bootstrap on react web applications. Try to apply to your codebase in a similar fashion.

Reference (P.S. These are referring to the react-bootstrap package):
https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970
https://medium.com/@vladbezden/webpack-configuration-for-using-bootstrap-in-react-a6ef2dfa1d95

Comment: Well, I analyzed your links, but then I went to the webpack documentation, and finally I figured it out how to bundle. However, i get `$ is not defined`, it looks like Jquery is not correctly imported. I don't know what I'm missing (I will edit my answer with code)

Comment: Im Glad it worked out! Thank you for mentioning me and I learnt something new too! 

Also, If you think Our conversation helped you get a solution, Feel free to give my answer an upvote, this will help me as well :D